# Load Image to dynamically created imageviews after a select photo intent

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent

i have a dynamically created tablelayout with dynamically created imageview per row.

[image]

These imageviews are clickable and will show a "select photo intent"
[image]

After selecting/capturing a photo, the image will be loaded in the imageview.
[image]

My problem is that, the image always load at the latest imageview created even if i choose the first one.
[image]

Code below:

```
public class ImageGalleryDemoActivity extends Activity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private Uri outputFileUri;
private ImageView imageView;
private int size = 2;

ImageView imageview_attachrequirement;

TableLayout tablelayout_coverages;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tablelayout_coverages = (TableLayout) findViewById(
            R.id.tablelayout_coverages);
    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    setCoverageTableLayout();
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            openImageIntent();
        }
    });
}

private void openImageIntent() {

    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,
            "Select Source");

    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
            cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if (data == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            } else {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if (action == null) {
                    isCamera = false;
                } else {
                    isCamera = action
                            .equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if (isCamera) {
                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                options.inSampleSize = 8;

                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                        selectedImageUri.getPath(), options);

                imageview_attachrequirement.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, false));

            } else {
                selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();

                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        selectedImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                imageview_attachrequirement.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(picturePath), 50, 50, false));

            }

        }
    }
}


private void setCoverageTableLayout() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        imageview_attachrequirement = new ImageView(this);
        imageview_attachrequirement.setId(i+1);

        imageview_attachrequirement.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        imageview_attachrequirement.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        imageview_attachrequirement.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

        final int index = i;

        imageview_attachrequirement.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {



                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Clicked Button Index :" + index, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                openImageIntent();

            }
        });


        row.addView(imageview_attachrequirement);

        TextView textview_coveragedescription = new TextView(this);
        textview_coveragedescription.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textview_coveragedescription.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);


        textview_coveragedescription.setText(String.valueOf(i));

        row.addView(textview_coveragedescription);

        TextView textview_coverageamount = new TextView(this);
        textview_coverageamount.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        textview_coverageamount.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        textview_coverageamount.setText(String.valueOf(i));

        row.addView(textview_coverageamount);

        tablelayout_coverages.addView(row);

    }

}
```

}

Is there a way that I can load the images to their respective imageview after the intent?

Thank you!!